# "Extend" a user's subcription with Stripe using Laravel cashier?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Stripe to manage a subscription service, and Laravel Cashier as my API interface for Stripe's services.

I have a situation where I want to sign a user up to a service, and then occasionally, extend their subscription beyond the original subscription end date by an arbitrary amount. This is supported by Stripe, [and the recommended way of doing so](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-change-the-billing-cycle-of-a-subscription) is to use the "subscription update" endpoint and pass a new `trial_end` value and a `prorate` value of false/null.

What I'm wondering is if Laravel Cashier supports this functionality. I've tried:

```
$user->subscription()->noProrate()->trialFor($newSubscriptionEndDate);
```

But, my stripe dashboard doesn't appear to be showing the change registering.

Is this something I can accomplish using Cashier exclusively or do I need to use the native Stripe API? The `StripeGateway` class does have a number of methods pertaining to trials and end dates, but I'm having trouble deciphering their intended functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use swap afterwards, e.g.

```
$user->subscription()->noProrate()->trialFor($newSubscriptionEndDate)->swap();
```

You can see what swap does here:

https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/5.0/src/Laravel/Cashier/StripeGateway.php#L181-L215

It returns the create method which actually updates as well if a customer object is passed through, so I'm assuming without that your changes won't make it to Stripe.

---

Here's a reference to someone using the same method with swap()
https://github.com/laravel/cashier/pull/142

If you have problems saving the new trial date in your local DB there is a setTrialEndDate method in your Billable trait (used in your user model) which you can see here:

https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/5.0/src/Laravel/Cashier/Billable.php#L437-L448

You should be able to use it like this:

```
$user->setTrialEndDate( $date )->save();
```

EDIT

```
// getStripeKey is a static method
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( $user::getStripeKey() );

// Get stripe id for customer using public method
$cu = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve( $user->getStripeId() );

// Get current stripe subscription id using public method
$subscription = $cu->subscriptions->retrieve( $user->getStripeSubscription() );

// Update trial end date and save
$subscription->trial_end = $date;
$subscription->save();
```

Then you can update it in Cashier manually with:

```
$user->setTrialEndDate( $date )->save();
```

Comment: Hmm. Interesting, that is pretty much what I would like to accomplish. However, as it stands, by calling `swap()` without a subscription id parameter in the `subscription()` call yields the result:

`InvalidRequest in ApiRequestor.php line 102: You passed an empty string for 'plan'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'plan' cannot be unset. You should remove 'plan' from your request or supply a non-empty value.`

Which I guess makes sense, because a plan cannot unset. Does this mean I need to create a `hold` plan with Stripe? How does this work when they get...

Comment: ...rebilled once their original subscription expires? Are they automatically rebilled on the $0 hold plan?

Comment: @EchoLogic You could try swapping them onto a hold plan, updating their trial time in the process and then swapping them back onto the original plan again (trial times will persist between plans unless modified) - there seems to be a total lack of information regarding updating a trial time outside of creating a subscription unfortunately.

Comment: @EchoLogic I've also added an example of how to do this at a lower level using a combination of Cashier and Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a new function in your model (in which you have used `Billable` trait, probably `User`):

```
class User extends Model implements BillableContract
{
    use Billable;

    public function MyCustomeCashierFunction($newSubscriptionEndDate)
    {
        retrun $this->subscription()->noProrate()->trialFor($newSubscriptionEndDate); 
    }
}
```

Then you can use this function with your model object in your controller:

```
$user->MyCustomeCashierFunction($newSubscriptionEndDate);
```

**Edit:**

Also try this if the function didn't work:

```
public function MyCustomeCashierFunction($newSubscriptionEndDate)
{
    $stripe_gateway = new StripeGateway($this);

    retrun $stripe_gateway->subscription()->noProrate()->trialFor($newSubscriptionEndDate); 
}
```

Please let me know if it works.